# CSS: Input type submit button disappears on Mac Safari 9 (El capitan)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

Help please, my web application doesn't show the `Submit Button` at the end of the application.  Yes it was working perfectly until someone tried to submit an application using **Safari 9 (El Capitan)** .  And so, he said that there is not `submit button`.  I checked today, and no `submit button` at all

I tried to add this css: (From another answer, but it didn't work)

```
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

**Edit:**

I am using `bootstrap 3` just in case.

Edit:

My `input` is:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-width bkgrnd-cyan" name="user_form"    
value="Submit" >
```

**CSS:**

```
    @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */



body{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#333;
}



input:read-only{
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#no-change {
  color:white;
}


/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/
.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn-blue {
    border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    color:#012d6b;
}
.btn-silver {
    border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color:#012d6b;
}

/*
  ========================================
   Headings
  ========================================
*/
h1,
.h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}

h2,
.h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
}

h3,
.h3 {
    font-size: 24px;

}

h4,
.h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h5,
.h5 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

h6,
.h6 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: Impact,Haettenschweiler,"Franklin Gothic Bold",Charcoal,"Helvetica Inserat","Bitstream Vera Sans Bold","Arial Black",sans serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/*
  ========================================
Page Formatting
  ========================================
*/

/*
   ======================================
Layout
   ======================================
*/
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    max-width: 900px;
}
.container:before,
.container:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.container:after {
    clear: both;
}

.header {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.header {
    margin-bottom: 20px; 
}
.header:before,
.header:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.header:after {
    clear: both;
}
.header  .row {
    position: relative;
}

.header .app-title{ 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align:right;

}

.nav-tabs li{
   background-color:#ECEDEA;
   border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#012d6b;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}
footer .container{
    padding:30px;
    height:55px;
}
footer small{
    float:right;
}

.control-label-red:after { 
    content:"*";
    color:red;
}


.instructions{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #999;
}

legend{
    width:inherit; /* Or auto */
    margin:0 20px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
    border-bottom:none;
    padding:0 10px; /* To give a bit of padding on the left and right */
}
fieldset{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;


}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    fieldset {
        display: table-cell;
    }
}


div {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}


.div-custom {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

textarea{
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}


#required{
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.instructionBig {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #708090;
}

.labeltext {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #555;
}

.bodytext {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;

}

tr.something{
    td {
    width: 90px;
  }
}

td{
    padding: 3px;


}

.bodytext {
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
}

.td-extra-espace{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#textarea-space{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}



.space{
    padding: 5px;
}



.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}


.btn-status{
    width:100%; 
    padding-right:20px; 
    padding-left:20px;
}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus, .btn:hover{
    outline: 0;
}


.btn-custom { 
    background-color: hsl(195, 79%, 90%) !important; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#12c10e104", endColorstr="#d1eff9"); 
    background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#12c10e104), to(#d1eff9)); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #12c10e104, #d1eff9); 
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #12c10e104, #d1eff9); 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #12c10e104), color-stop(100%, #d1eff9)); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #12c10e104, #d1eff9);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #12c10e104, #d1eff9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#12c10e104, #d1eff9);
    border-color: #d1eff9 #d1eff9 hsl(195, 79%, 85%); 
    color: #333 !important; 
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.33); 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}


.bold{ 
  font-weight: bold;  
}

.btn-transparent{

        border: none;
        background: transparent;
}



.well-custom{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#edit-space{
    padding-bottom:0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


.modal-body{
     padding-right: 50px;

}

@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}


.border-between > [class*='col-']:before {
 background: #e3e3e3;
 bottom: 0;
 content: " ";
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 1.5px;
 top: 0;
}
.border-between > [class*='col-']:first-child:before {
 display: none;
}

.form-control-custom{
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 80%;
}

.hr-custom{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
  padding-right:5px;
  padding-left:0;
}

.btn-width{
    width:130px;

}

.input-size{
    width: 50%;
}

.input-grade{
    width: 30%;
}


.input-group .form-control {
    height: 22px;
    font-size: 9px;
}

#myModal {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

label.error{
    color:red;
}

select.error{
    border-color: red;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input[type="radio"]{
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.input-background
{
   border: 0px;
   background-color: #fff;
   background: transparent;
}


.form-control[disabled], .form-control[readonly], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) inset;

}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus, .btn:hover {
    color: #FFF;

}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 180px;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    height: 25px;
}

.dl-horizontal dt {
    width: 170px;
}
```

Comment: your code is too small to answer this question, it can be caused by many factors... give us at least styles and html code of your form/button

Comment: there you go, thanks for your reply

Comment: Try to make it <button>, not <input>, and if it will not help - try to set display: block; and height / line height properties - will it appear?

Comment: @AndrewEvt yes did work...but, `<button>` with `type=submit`? is that possible? and safe?

Comment: Yes, button with type submit. Read more about on w3c site

Comment: Let me try the `<input>` with the `display:block` to see what happen

Comment: You can try whatever you want :) I just can tell you 1 way, but each problem have few ways to go :) you choose what way you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my `CSS` I have the following code:

```
input:read-only{
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

This was making my submit button transparent.  So, I just delete this part and the code works fine on **Safari 9 (El Capitan)**